# Get next object in Array useState React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, api, use-state

Iam building a quiz-website as practice for React and want to be able to change question with a button. When I change useState(0) manually to 1 the next object renders. But i cant get it to work with the button. When i click the button it jumps straight to the alert message.

```
function GetMovies() {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchItems();
  }, []);

  const [items, setItems] = useState({ options: [] });

  const fetchItems = async () => {
    const data = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/movies");
    const items = await data.json();
    //test
    //console.log(items[currentQuestion]);
    setItems(items[currentQuestion]);
  };

  
  const [currentQuestion, setCurrentQuestion] = useState(0);

  //change question solution that dont work
  const HandleAnswerButtonClick = () => {
    const nextQuestion = setCurrentQuestion + 1;
    if (nextQuestion < items.length) {
      setCurrentQuestion(nextQuestion);
    } else {
      alert("End of quiz");
    }
    setCurrentQuestion(nextQuestion);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Quiza</h1>
      <div>
        <span>Question 1</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h3>Question: {items.description}</h3>
        {items.options.map((c) => (
          <button value={c.is_correct} key={c.text}>
            {c.text}
          </button>
        ))}
        <div>
        {//Next BUTTON}
          <button onClick={() => HandleAnswerButtonClick()}>
            Next question
          </button>
        </div>
        {/* if-sats, om bild finns till frågan visas den, annars en class med display none */}
        <div className="Q_pics">
          {items.options.map((c) =>
            !c.image ? (
              <p className="Display_none">empty</p>
            ) : (
              <img src={c.image} alt={c.text}></img>
            )
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**The mongoose schema from my API**

```
const MovieSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    category: { type: String, required: true },
    description: { type: String, required: true },
    image: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    options: [
      {
        text: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
        is_correct: {
          type: Boolean,
          required: true,
          default: false,
        },
        image: {
          type: String,
          required: false,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  { collection: "movies" }
);
```

Comment: You should be setting your `items` to the array of movie objects you get back from your endpoint so that you can change which item you display. Currently, it looks like you're setting it to a specific movie object, so it won't have a `.length` property and will mean you'll need to ask you endpoint for the array of items again next time you change the question. Tip for debugging is to log your variables. As you're having an issue with your if-statement, you can use `console.log(nextQuestion, items.length)` to see what your if-statement is checking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because

```
const nextQuestion = setCurrentQuestion + 1;
```

should be

```
const nextQuestion = currentQuestion + 1;
```

---

Oh, and as @Nick Parsons mentioned in a comment, you also only store the first question in your state, since the `fetchItems` is only run once, and you do `setItems(items[currentQuestion]);`

You should do something like

```
function GetMovies() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);    
  const [currentQuestion, setCurrentQuestion] = useState(0);

  const fetchItems = async () => {
    const data = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/movies");
    const items = await data.json();
    //test
    //console.log(items[currentQuestion]);
    setItems(items);
  };
  
  //change question solution that dont work
  const HandleAnswerButtonClick = () => {
    const nextQuestion = currentQuestion + 1;
    if (nextQuestion < items.length) {
      setCurrentQuestion(nextQuestion);
    } else {
      alert("End of quiz");
    }
    setCurrentQuestion(nextQuestion);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchItems();
  }, []);

  const activeQuestion = items[currentQuestion];
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Quiza</h1>
      <div>
        <span>Question {currentQuestion + 1}</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h3>Question: {activeQuestion && activeQuestion.description}</h3>
        {activeQuestion && activeQuestion.options.map((c) => (
          <button value={c.is_correct} key={c.text}>
            {c.text}
          </button>
        ))}
        <div>
        {//Next BUTTON}
          <button onClick={() => HandleAnswerButtonClick()}>
            Next question
          </button>
        </div>
        {/* if-sats, om bild finns till frågan visas den, annars en class med display none */}
        <div className="Q_pics">
          {activeQuestion && activeQuestion.options.map((c) =>
            !c.image ? (
              <p className="Display_none">empty</p>
            ) : (
              <img src={c.image} alt={c.text}></img>
            )
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still skips straight to the alert message

Comment: @Haddock see Nick's comment on your question

Comment: Alright this seems to work, but on refreshing the page i get a blank page and the console says "Uncaught TypeError: activeQuestion is undefined". Last time this happend I used "const [item, setItem] = useState({ options: [] });"  but that wont do the trick this time.

when deleting  "<h2>{activeQuestion.description}</h2>", it works fine.

Comment: @Haddock a yes. the `{activeQuestion.description}` should also have a guard like `{activeQuestion && activeQuestion.description}`. But you might want to `return null` if `activeQuestion` is `undefined` so that you do not have to guard at each place.

Answer (score 0):

the code might be like this:

```
  const [items, setItems] = useState({ options: [] });
    // currentIdx might be a better name
  const [currentIdx, setCurrentIdx] = useState(0);
  const fetchItems = async () => {
    const data = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/movies");
    const items = await data.json();
        //  save all data as Nick said. and items should be type of Data[];
    setItems(items);
  };
  const HandleAnswerButtonClick = () => {
    const nextQuestion = currentIdx + 1;
    if (nextQuestion < items.length) {
      setCurrentIdx(nextQuestion);
    } else {
      alert("End of quiz");
    }
  };
    // use displayItem for render 
  const displayItem = useMemo(() => items[currentIdx], [items, currentIdx]);
```

you'd better learn to use dev tools and watch values of your code I think